# записать в виде генератора

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
for x, y in zip(c,a):
  for i in range(y-1):
    print(x,end="")
```

Так выглядит финальная часть работающего кода, но изначально хотел записать в виде генератора, но не вышло.Помогите с этим плиз.(в списке "a" хранятся числа, в списке "c" хранятся буквенные значения в формате str, результат всего кода выглядит так:

> PPPPPPPPPZZZZZZZZZZZZZQQQQQQQQQQQQQQaaaaaaaaaaaaaaFFFFFFFFFFFFFwwwwwwwwwwTTTTTxxxxxxxkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkpppppppppppppppGGGGGGGGHHHHHHHHHHHHQHHHHHHHHHHqqqqZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZJJJcccccccOOOOOBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCgggggggggggggaaaaGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO

То есть вывод должен быть чистым без кавычек, скобок и т.д.

Comment: Вы бы ещё пример входных данных показали.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, да ладно, и так вроде понятно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://ideone.com/Cs7qDM

```
print("".join(s*i for i,s in zip([1,4,2,5], ['a','q','s','z'])))
```

s*i - умножение строки на число. `"А"*3` будет `"ААА"`